# Compress image using sharp in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, image-compression, sharp

I want to resize and compress images using `sharp` in `node.js`

In sharp for `jpeg` there is separate compression and for `webp` there is separate and for `png` there is separate.

WEBP

```
sharp('a.jpg')
.resize(1000)
.webp({quality: 80})
```

JPEG

```
sharp('_4_.jpg')
 .resize(1000)
 .jpeg({quality: 80})
```

PNG

```
sharp('_4_.jpg')
 .resize(1000)
 .png({compressionLevel: 8})
```

Basically I want to compress and resize image without checking in which format they.

Is there anything for that in `sharp` ?

Comment: Why don't you just check the extension and act accordingly? If you want a more precise detection you can read the first bytes of the image, but I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: yes that's a solution but i want to do same instead of checks

Comment: I check but not find...that's why I post question

Comment: different formats require different method decoding and encoding, so checking extension is a good idea.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the output format to match the input format, you should look at `force` option.

```
sharp(input)
  .jpeg({ progressive: true, force: false })
  .png({ progressive: true, force: false })
  ...
```

GIF output is not supported, so GIF input will become PNG output by default.

Additional reference: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#jpeg

Answer (score 8):

You can grab file format with `metadata` method and select according optimisation method for it:

```js
const image = sharp('_4_.jpg')
const meta = await image.metadata()
const { format } = meta

const config = {
  jpeg: { quality: 80 },
  webp: { quality: 80 },
  png: { compressionLevel: 8 },
}

await image[format](config[format])
  .resize(1000)
```

Answer (score 6):

PNG is also `quality`, but as it is a lossless format, this is set to `100` by default.  Where-as JPG is set to `80` by default.

By reducing the `quality` for PNG, it will enable the `palette` mode which will reduce the number of colours captured in the encoding.  This will provide some good size reduction for the file.

`compression` is just zlib / zip compression, haven't found it does much TBH.

All in the docs: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#png

```
// this will disable loss-less mode, and reduce the colour accuracy to 90%
// it will also enable the palette
sharp('_4_.jpg')
 .resize(1000)
 .png({quality: 90})
```